# SAML2.0 Specification how Response Should be sent

Tags: java, saml-2.0, idp, ratpack, pac4j

I have connected to two different saml2.0 identity providers.
Test IdP https://hub.docker.com/r/kristophjunge/test-saml-idp/
And a Third party idp.

I am new to SAML so I may be missing something here. 
It turns out that the test idp works perfectly with the demo code at (https://github.com/pac4j/ratpack-pac4j-demo).
On login, the context Session contains `Pac4jSessionKeys.USER_PROFILE`.

However, for the other idp the profile does not end up in the session. The session contains only  `Pac4jSessionKeys.REQUESTED_URL`

On login the id responds with a XHTML form specified like in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0
This response is sent in the body. This is not the case for the test idp which seems to work well with the test code above.

Since I am not familiar with SAML2.0 I am wondering if there are different specs I am not aware of?

Do I have to parse the XHTML body myself?
I suppose if this is the standard way to do things then ratpack will already have support for this.

Comment: Which binding type do you use?

Comment: I use both Redirect and POST.
The third party idp seems to use post when sending back to my applications

Comment: Your application is web-based, right?

Comment: Yes it is a web appplication. Yes

Comment: When you use POST binding, SAML Response is embedded inside a form. Then the IDP sends this form inside an HTML page along with a simple javascript which is responsible for automatic redirection. Is your third-party idp in compliance with these procedures?

Comment: oh really? Where is this specification document? In other words you are saying that pac4j expects only a redirect? So if the the IDp is not compliant then i would have to parse and verify the form myself?\

Comment: I changed my service to use Redirect binding it was previously defaulting to the POST Binding. I still experience the same issue though. The thirdparty service provider supports Redirect Binding

Comment: My bad. My callback url on the idp was not right. Works fine now.